# jquerymobile one page with different meta viewport settings

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've tried adjusting my meta `viewport` tag on a jQM `beforepageshow` etc it simply doesn't work and I guess that's pretty obvious why. I have one page with a highcharts chart on it and I need to have nothing inside my viewport tag which normally has `width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0`

and that's because I want the app to zoom out when the chunky chart goes in, has anyone had any brilliant ideas on how to have one page with different `viewport` settings? I could link to it without AJAX and then output the right meta tag conditionally but I'd rather not do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dynamically changed the meta `viewport` tag on a couple of my mobile websites when I want to enable zooming for an image or something else that requires the user looking at small text:

```
var $viewport        = $('meta[name="viewport"]'),
    default_viewport = $viewport.attr('content');

$(document).delegate('#page-id-one, #page-id-two', 'pageshow', function () {

    //these are the pages that you want to enable zooming
    $viewport.attr('content', 'width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=5.0');

}).delegate('#page-id-one, #page-id-two', 'pagehide', function () {

    $viewport.attr('content', default_viewport);

});
```

This code expects to be included after jQuery and the meta `viewport` tag. You can obviously change the contents of the `viewport` element as you see fit (I believe that Safari will allow a `maximum-scale` of `10`).

Comment: Hiya, this is working for me (as in its changing the content value) but the browser doesn't seem to register that the viewport has changed, so I can't do anything, r u sure thats working 4 u?

Comment: @Baconbeastnz http://m.peppermillreno.com/#propertymap1 . Works for me on my Android (2.3.3) and my iPhone (5.0.1). On the page I linked to it should allow zooming but if you go "Back" it won't allow you to zoom.

Comment: ahok ive got it going now thanks, if you try and change the viewport scale on the fly you run into some dodgey effects, 1/2 width etc, u can adjust it but looks nasty