# Can I have jquery mobile working without the ui-mobile class in the html tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, compatibility

I think having this class added to the html tag is causing this tag not to work as is supposed to.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Some examples I found online show that they put the second meta element after the view port.

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Starter page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>`

http://www.appliness.com/getting-started-with-html-mobile-application-development-using-jquery-mobile-requirejs-and-backbonejs/

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/jquery-mobile-need-to-know/

Changing page meta: [jquerymobile one page with different meta viewport settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394319/jquerymobile-one-page-with-different-meta-viewport-settings)

Comment: Sorry but no, that's not what I want to do, this tag you sent works for something different, maybe I didnt explain myself properly. When Jquery Mobile starts it adds ui-mobile class to the header tag, therefore IE wont read my header meta-tag. What Im doing now to make it work is sending the headers through php first and then loading my html page. Didnt test it 100% but I think is the way to go. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working as I said, basically if you want to use Jquery Mobile and the internet explorer "edge" meta-tag the best way to do it to make sure it will work is to send the headers through PHP and include the html file without headers, you can add styles and scripts in the body. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    header( 'X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1' ); 

    header( 'content: width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' );

    include('ix.html');
?>
```